# Vertical line between two button

Tags: html, css

I am developing an angular 2 app with angular material. I have two buttons sign in and sign up I want a vertical line between the two buttons; I saw many examples on different sites but it doesn't work. I want that the buttons be on same line (inline and between them a little vertical line).
this is the html code :

```css
.textAlign {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* à 50%/50% du parent référent */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}

.ligne_verticale {
  width: 5px;
  border-left: 5px solid gray;
  height: 70px;
}

.nav-button {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <img class="image" src="http://seabramota.com/img/intro-bg.jpg" alt="image 
        d'accueil">
    <div class="textAlign">
      <h1>{{ 'PAGEHOME.TITLE' | translate }}</h1>
      <br>
      <h3>{{ 'PAGEHOME.DESCRIPTION' | translate }}</h3>
      <br>


      <button mat-button color="primary" class="nav-button" (click)="openConnectDialog()">
          {{ 'PAGEHOME.CONNECTBUTTON' | translate }}
        </button>


      <button mat-button color="primary" class="nav-button" (click)=" 
        openRegisterDialog()">
          {{ 'PAGEHOME.INSCRIREBUTTON' | translate }}
        </button>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: put a div with class .ligne_verticale between the buttons and wrap the buttons in a div class="row" if you are using bootstrap or foundation or set display: inline for both buttons and the div

Comment: Please update the snippet I made to make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that ?

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  background: #99A3FF;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.button-container {
  padding: 12px 24px;
}

.button-container:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-container"><button>Register</button></div>
  <div class="button-container"><button>Log In</button></div>
</div>
```