# Adding a vertical line between buttons

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code. I am trying to add a vertical line that seperates the login and sign up buttons, anybody have an idea how to do this?

```
 <header class="header">
   <h1>The Textbook Marketplace</h1>
     <div class="header-buttons">
       <button class="btn login-btn">Log In</button>
       <button class="btn signup-btn">Sign Up</button>
     </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: What do you have so far ? What is the issue with your code?

Comment: @Woohaik I have tried using a div but it takes up too much space and the background doesn't match. Maybe I can just change the background of the div to transparent?

Comment: `::after` and `::before`

Comment: Wrap the buttons in a container and set a border on the container. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49401653/16202800)

Answer (score 2):

add a div between them and give it proper height width and color

```css
.line{
  background-color:black;
  height:20px;
  width:3px;
}

.header-buttons{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.btn{
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1>The Textbook Marketplace</h1>
  <div class="header-buttons">
<button class="btn login-btn">Log In</button>
<div class="line"></div>
<button class="btn signup-btn">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends of the height you want for the line. But I think the solution would be to put a border (for ex: solid 2px black) on the right border of the left button or vice versa if you put a border for the right button. Or, create a `<div>` between the two buttons and play with background color or the borders.

Comment: So you're saying to just style a border for the left button and put padding on it to center the line? Also, I already have a solid border surrounding both buttons so I don't think this will work

Comment: That would be the idea yes, but be careful playing with padding for styling. But Nathan linked a post above which explains it very well.